# How to exclude or-marker-p when using (<= deadline today)

Tags: emacs

`deadline` and `today` are both numeric values defined within another function.  I'm trying to use less-than-or-equal-to, or greater-than-or-equal-to, within a function similar to a recent thread of mine:  [How to test for org-todo state "xyz" with deadline not equal to today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602498/how-to-test-for-org-todo-state-xyz-with-deadline-not-equal-to-today)

In this particular case, my function contains a condition of `(<= deadline today)` and the function works properly if I don't unwittingly set any marks beforehand.  If I unwittingly set a mark beforehand (e.g., by going to the end of the buffer before running the function), then I get an error message `and: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`.  I've tried inserting into the function `(deactivate-mark)` with a t and with setq and mark nil and `transient-mark-mode -1`, but I cannot get around that error.  I haven't found a way to clear all markers from the mark-ring.  Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

```
(defun carry-forward-uncompleted-todo (&optional from-state to-state)

"Carry forward uncompleted todo."

  (interactive)

  (let* (

      (element (org-element-at-point))

      (todo-state (org-element-property :todo-keyword element))

      (deadline

        (ignore-errors ;; avoids throwing error message if there is no deadline.

        (time-to-days

        (org-time-string-to-time

        (org-element-property :deadline element) ))))

      (today (time-to-days (current-time))) )

    (goto-char (point-min))

    (while

      (re-search-forward "^\*\* Active" nil t)

      (when (< deadline today) ;; condition -- past-due

        (org-deadline nil ".") ;; make deadline today

      )

    )

  )

)
```

Sample *.org file.

```
* TASKS

** Active [#A] First task due today. :lawlist:
   DEADLINE: <2013-07-11 Thu >

** Active [#A] Second task due today. :lawlist:
   DEADLINE: <2013-07-11 Thu >

** Next Action [#E] Test One -- make Active with deadline today. :lawlist:
   DEADLINE: <2013-07-31 Wed >

** Next Action [#E] Test Two -- make Active with deadline today. :lawlist:
   DEADLINE: <2013-07-31 Wed >
```

---

EDIT -- SOLUTION -- special thanks to Nicholas Riley for helping to troubleshoot the issue.

```
(defvar from-state nil)
(defvar to-state nil)

(defun carry-forward-uncompleted-tasks ()
"Carry forward uncompleted tasks."
(interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "^\*\* Active" nil t)
    (unless (org-at-heading-p)
      (org-back-to-heading))
    (let* (
        (element (org-element-at-point))
        (todo-state (org-element-property :todo-keyword element))
        (deadline
          (ignore-errors ;; avoids throwing an error message if there is no deadline.
          (time-to-days
          (org-time-string-to-time
          (org-element-property :deadline element) ))))
        (today (time-to-days (current-time)))
        (title (org-element-property :raw-value element)) )
      (setq from-state "Active")
      (setq to-state "Active")
      (if (and
        (> today deadline) ;; condition -- deadline is overdue
        (string= todo-state from-state) ) ;; condition -- todo-state equals from-state
          (progn ;; Process following list if conditions were met.
            (message "\nMODIFIED => Active + Today:  %s" title)
            (org-deadline nil ".") )
        (message "\nNO CHANGES:  %s" title)) )))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing.  It would be best if you could post a self-contained example of elisp that triggers the problem you are trying to describe.

That said, I'll try to answer: It looks like either `deadline` or `today` are `nil` rather than whatever you're expecting.  `<=` expects both of its arguments to be either a number or a marker, hence why it's ensuring that with `number-or-marker-p`.  Probably something relating to setting the mark writes `nil` to one of these variables.

It's unclear what you mean by "numeric values defined within another function" — how and where are the variables defined (`defvar`? `let`?) and where are they written?  If you don't understand Emacs's scopes and dynamic binding (and lexical binding in Emacs 24+), you should read about them.  Those variable names don't have a prefix, which is pretty dangerous depending on their scope.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to post the actual function at issue -- I've edited the question and added the additional information.  The function works if I don't set any marks before running the function -- i.e., if I just open Emacs and run the function, it works.  If I open Emacs and go to the bottom of the buffer with `end-of-buffer`, then I see a `Mark set` occurring, which is what causes the problem with running `carry-forward-uncompleted-todo` -- if after receiving the error message, I try to run the function again, it works.  `Mark set` is from the function `push-mark` in simple.el

Comment: OK.  You might consider using `save-excursion` if you're going to be moving the point around inside your function.  You've got `ignore-errors` wrapping the value of `deadline`, I imagine what is most likely is that `deadline` is nil.  I'd suggest you just go down your `let*` with print statements or a debugger and make sure everything is as you expect.  (BTW — I tried running your function on every heading of the org file you posted, both with and without setting the mark. It worked fine.)

Comment: Yes, you were correct -- temporarily removing the `ignore-errors` and enabling debugging was very helpful.  I believe the issue described in this thread was because the variables defined with `let*` preceded the search forward, which didn't work properly because each task needs to be evaluated separately as the search proceeds down the list one by one.  I've changed the order of the function and I believe that resolves the issue.  I'm posting the corrected function as an edit to the initial question.  Thank you for helping me to troubleshoot what was happening -- greatly appreciated !!!  :)